# How to treat hyper link as actual link and not flask route?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I want to make a link in html that is an actual link and not a flask route. That link is somewhere on my computer which starts as '/Users/....'. 
This link is being treated as flask route. But I don't want that. How to fix this? 
The code looks something like this

```py
@app.route('/')
def home():
  p = '/Users/...'
  return render_template('home.html',path=p)
```

and

```html
<body>
<video width="1920" height="1080" controls>
<source src='{{path}}' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
</body>
```

Comment: Is that a link to a `src="file://{{path}}`?

Comment: I am on Mac so the path goes '/Users' (Absolute path). And the link is to a video file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attributes), `src` is a url (The URL of the video to embed) and since you've made it a relative path/url, Flask will try to find a route for it. To prevent this, you need to either make it an absolute URL or add code to 'intercept' clicking the video (url) and then do what you want with the value of src